# PHP Function returning mysql_fetch_assoc() results in index based array?

Tags: php, mysql, function, return, associative-array

this is my first post here, in the past I found all my questions already solved.
Not this time so please help me :-)!

- Why is `$returned_assoc_arr` holding an index based array instead of the associative?
- I also tried it with a reference `public function &fetch_assoc($res)` but without luck?
- Is there any way to fix this? I really need this to be an associative array..

I hope I explained everything quite well and some Senior PHP Coders can help with this.

Here we go with the code snippets:

file1.php

```
public function fetch_assoc($res) {
  $assoc_arr = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($assoc_arr);
  echo "</pre>";
  return $assoc_arr;
}
```

file2.php

```
$returned_assoc_arr = $foo->fetch_assoc($res);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($returned_assoc_arr);
echo "</pre>";
```

Output from file2.php:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 42
    [Client] => 1
    [DebtorAccountNumber] => 1234512345
    [OrderDate] => 2001-04-03 02:00:00
    [Status] => 1
    [Comment] => this is a comment
    [CreatedBy] => 1
    [Reference] => 2083137729
)

Array
(
    [0] => 42
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 1234512345
    [3] => 2001-04-03 02:00:00
    [4] => 1
    [5] => this is a comment
    [6] => 1
    [7] => 2083137729
)
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that this is all the code that's working on the data? As what you're describing shouldn't be happening.

Comment: This code sample doesn't make any sense. Your method has an access modifier, which requires the method class to be defined within a class, but your method call of fetch_assoc, does not relate to the class with which the method is in. I therefore echo Yoshi's sentiments, are yu sure you are using this method when working on the data?

Comment: I'm not a PHP senior developer, so can I help you? Gosh...

Answer (score 1):

The method fetch_assoc is a member function of a class. (it's invoked on the containing object, which must be instantiated first)

what you are using in file2 is a ordinary function fetch_assoc, which definitely is different than the function described in file1.

Comment: Yes i'm sure I changed to code snipped it was misstyped by my self..
I'm calling the method fetch_assoc() from an object ($foo).

I really don't know why this is like that.. still have not figured out why..

Comment: Most of the array functions will remove associative keys, so there is something happening that we cannot see in your snippets.  Can you post more of your code (or the complete set) to pastebin.